# Can only reset cinder volume state as the admin user

Tags: openstack, policy, cinder, openstack-cinder

## Issue

- Unable to reset cinder volume state as non-admin user.
- What needs to be done so that users can reset volume states
- The following is an example the error seen when only the admin user is allowed to reset volume state:

```
$ cinder reset-state --state available 5d94365a-3351-4a7f-8aab-b4795daf955c
WARNING:cinderclient.shell:API version 3.60 requested,
WARNING:cinderclient.shell:downgrading to 3.59 based on server support.
Policy doesn't allow volume_extension:volume_admin_actions:reset_status to be performed. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-2892f77e-697b-43aa-9eb7-062d49bda0fc)
ERROR: Unable to reset the state for the specified entity(s).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create/change `/etc/cinder/policy.json` to include the following line:

```
"volume_extension:volume_admin_actions:reset_status": "rule:admin_or_owner"
```

This will allow the owner of a volume to reset the state.

Comment: Note that in the most recent versions of Cinder, there is no policy.json file. The default policy rules are hardcoded, but if a policy.json file exists, it overrides the rules. Therefore, if you have no policy.json file, create one that contains just the above rule.